# Unable to open an existing notebook in IPython Notebook

Tags: firefox, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I want to open a notebook, say 'IPython - beyond normal Python'. To achieve this, I perform the following steps, in order.

1. Move to the place where IPython Notebook is installed.
2. cd to 'Notebooks'. iPython dashboard opens in a browser with list of available notebooks.
3. Click on the desired notebook.

The third step opens a new tab, but I can't see the contents of the notebook. A screen shot of what appears under that tab is shown below.[image: Contents of the new tab that opens upon completion of step 3.]

How can I see the contents of the notebook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that the notebook format [is v3](https://github.com/ipython/ipython-in-depth/blob/master/notebooks/IPython%20-%20beyond%20plain%20Python.ipynb#L5) and you are running IPython v0.12 that only read notebook v3. There is a warning message in newer versions if the notebook version is more recent than IPython.

Also IPython, not iPython if possible.

Comment: Hi Matt, Thanks for the reply. I upgraded my IPython to v0.13, and that solves my issues.

Comment: Great, there even should be a 0.13.2 release with bugfixes, if it's not on Ubuntu main repository, it's probably on Julian Taylor PPA : https://launchpad.net/~jtaylor/+archive/ipython-dev just in case :-)